# Spring MVC - Mutiple Forms (image upload and other details) handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new in spring - mvc and please help me out by giving some pointers on below question.

I am trying out a form submission/processing using spring mvc + thyme leaf. We have a sign up form asking user details (first, last name, email etc) and a field for uploading the image. In the controller, we should be able to upload the image (file system upload rather than saving in DB) and save other details entered in db.

Any pointers on this?

Thanks,
VIjay

Comment: Atleast try something..post your code..we will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at the spring guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be comment. When you answer the question, answer should be related to the questions in essence.